# Вызов virtual метода базового класса из класса-потомка

Tags: c#

Условно говоря имею базовый класс A и его класс наследник B. Класс A имеет виртуальный метод, в классе наследнике он переопределяется. Вопрос: могу ли на объекте-наследнике вызвать еще не переопределенный метод базового класса (тот самый который virual), и если да, то как?

```
class A
{
 public virtual void myMethod() {}
} 

class B : A
{
 public override void myMethod() {}
}

Нужно что бы в вызывающей части программы было что то вроде этого:
B b = new B();
b.myMethod(); // но метод базового класса
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно так, естественно, не получится:

```
B b = new B();
b.myMethod();
```

т.к. это явное обращение к методу класса `B`.

Если нужно одновременно и переопределить метод и иметь возможность вызвать старую реализацию, то можно для нее выделить новый старый метод:

```
/// <summary>
/// Вызов метода с такими-то особенностями, присущими классу A
/// Лучше дать ему название, описывающее отличия в поведении от myMethod
/// </summary>
public void oldMyMethod()
{
    base.myMethod();
}
```

Другое дело если Вам требуется избавиться от полиморфизма:

```
var a = (A)b;
//здесь вызывается метод из В, а нужен метод из А
a.myMethod();
```

в этом случае надо отказываться от виртуальности `myMethod`, т.к. весь ее смысл в том, чтобы вызывался переопределенный метод.

```
class B : A
{
    //с помощью new прячем метод и ломаем полиморфизм
    public new void myMethod() {}
}

class A
{
    //технически у предка можно оставить virtual
    //например, если метод переопределяется в других наследниках.
    //, но в данном случае это теряет смысл.
    public void myMethod() {}
}
```

При таком подходе `B.myMethod` спрячет `A.myMethod`. Следует иметь ввиду, что абсолютно несвязанные методы с одинаковыми названиями сбивают с толку разработчиков при чтении кода. Поэтому, в этом случае имеет смысл дать методам разные названия.

Comment: У меня есть потребность в использовании как новой версии метода, так и старой. Как я понял, для достижения этого у меня есть два пути: 1) Выделить для этого новый метод (как вы написали oldMyMethod); 2) Привести наследника к предку и потом обратно. В целом ясно, спасибо

Comment: @АлексейФедотов Для виртуального метода приведение к предку не сработает. Все равно будет вызываться переопределенный. Чтобы вызывалась реализация предка нужно убрать `virtual` у `myMethod`

Comment: получается, единственный способ это определение нового метода в наследнике, где будет вызываться старый метод с помощью ключевого слова  base?

Comment: @АлексейФедотов да, по-моему это наиболее чистое решение, которое позволяет сохранить оба варианта вызова.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще в C# есть ключевое слово `base`. С его помощью вы можете в классе-наследнике обращаться к членам класса-предка. Например так:

```
class A
{
    public virtual void myMethod() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("parent");
    }
} 

class B : A
{
    public override void myMethod() 
    {
        base.myMethod(); // вызываете метод базового класса
        Console.WriteLine("child");
    }
}
```

Если вы напишете что-то такое:

```
B b = new B();
b.myMethod();
```

то на консоль выведется

> parent
>   child

Если вам нужно, чтобы выполнялась тоьлко логика метода базового класса, то метод доллжен быть таким:

```
public override void myMethod() 
{
    base.myMethod(); 
}
```

Но смысла в этом на самом деле нет, ведь если метод-потомок только вызывает метод-предок, то этот метод не нужно объявлять вовсе